# AWS: List of assigned IPs in subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-vpc, subnet

Is there a way to get a list of all assigned IPs in an AWS subnet?  Furthermore, if there is a way to see the associated (AW)Services?  That would be incredibly helpful as well.  Thanks!

**EDIT**:

All assigned private IPs in a private AWS Subnet (which are retained regardless of instance state).  Any means of obtaining this information will do.  I am most familiar with AWS CLI, boto/boto3 and the console.

The list would include all avail per CIDR block definition except for 5 addresses:

- 1 for subnet address
- 1 for broadcast
- [AWS reserves the first 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#VPC_Sizing) available IP addresses
  for each subnet

Comment: Define `assigned` IPs. Even stopped instances have an IP in a VPC. You want CLI solution or SDK solution? Be as descriptive as possible and avoid one liner questions.

Comment: Absolutely!  I've posted some edits above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=subnet-id,Values=subnet-12345678" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress' --output text
```

- Use `describe-instances`
- Query by `subnet-id`
- Filter the results by `PrivateIpAddress`

Using @Michael - sqlbot's suggestion:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters "Name=subnet-id,Values=subnet-12345678" --query 'NetworkInterfaces[*].PrivateIpAddress'
```

Comment: Thanks!   I'm noticing that this does not account for all of my unavailable subnet addresses from the AWS VPC subnet console.  I understand the two reserved for subnet address and broadcast.  Are they associated with RDS instances?  Is it possible to get the same thing for RDS instance?  I imagine that the addresses are behind an endpoint address to abstract MultiAZ, so I wasn't sure how much of this information is visible.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think [`aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-network-interfaces.html) would be the preferred approach, since that should pick up addresses used by RDS, ELB-C/ALB/NLB, EFS, PrivateLink, etc... not to mention the dynamic activity of Lambda.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I agree, but in my case both return same set of IPs. Thanks for mentioning Lambda. Are you saying Lambda uses up an IP in VPC IP address space?

Comment: @scagnetti what IPs are not accounted for? I mean the type of instances, instance state etc.,

Comment: @helloV Lambda allocates multiple elastic network interfaces -- apparently one for each container it spawns -- when functions are running inside your VPC.  [*"AWS Lambda uses the VPC information you provide to set up ENIs that allow your Lambda function to access VPC resources."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)  After a traffic spike, any excess ENIs are typically destroyed within a few hours of their last use.  The other services I mentioned all allocate ENIs and they're assigned addresses from your CIDR block for the subnets they are on.  Also NAT Gateways get 1 each.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: @scagnetti try the second solution using `describe-network-interfaces`

Comment: @helloV, taking one of my subnets as an example: 4096 addresses are the total according to the subnet definition.  Taking away 2 for broadcast and subnet, this leaves 4094.  The VPC subnet console lists 4079 as available, so I have to account for 15.  When I run the command with describe-instances I see 10 IPs.  When I run with describe-network-instances I get an additional 2 (for an EFS mount and an RDS instance).  15 available minus the 12 that I see with describe-network-interfaces leaves 3 that I would still like to account for.  I'm not sure where else they could be.  Thanks!

Comment: 3 minutes into a AWS Network Cert video by Cloud Guru, I'm told "AWS reserves the first 3 available IP addresses for each subnet".  I'll update the question with this detail, as I think it may be helpful for anyone with the same question.  @Michael-sqlbot & helloV, thank you so much for your help!!!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @scagnetti that's true.  [*"The first four IP addresses and the last IP address in each subnet CIDR block are not available for you to use, and cannot be assigned to an instance."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#VPC_Sizing)  Slightly different wording, but "first four" and "first 3 available" are the same, of course.

Comment: @helloV Can you replace the single quote with double quotes in the filter? I found that copying your example into windows AWS cli didn't work until I replaced the quotes with double quotes

Comment: More than one IP can be attached to each Network Interface, so this query is more effective: `'NetworkInterfaces[*].PrivateIpAddresses[*].PrivateIpAddress'`. The output isn't so pretty. Also, prefixes can also be allocated, so a query like `'NetworkInterfaces[*].Ipv4Prefixes[*].Ipv4Prefix'` is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the count of available IPs through this command:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids subnet-0621441200b4b3970 --query "Subnets[*].AvailableIpAddressCount"
```